# Geometry With Triangles With 3 Variables

Tags: geometry, triangles

The angles of a triangle are $x$,$y$ and $z$ in descending order.If $2x-y=100^\circ =3y-2z$ ,then its smallest angle is?

My answer is coming $40^\circ$ but the book is showing answer $60^\circ$ Is the answer really $60^\circ$ ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

We have the following relations: $$x+y+z = 180^\circ \tag 1$$ $$ x = \frac{y + 100^\circ}{2} \tag 2$$ $$z = \frac{3y -100^\circ}{2} \tag 3$$

Can you find $x,y,z$ from $(1)\, , (2)\, , (3)?$

Answer (score 0):

we get three equations
$$2x-y=100^{\circ}$$
$$3y-2z=100^{\circ}$$
$$x+y+z=180^{\circ}$$
can you solve this System?
solving this System we get $$80^{\circ},60^{\circ},40^{\circ}$$